# Email supposedly from the future mentioning fairly recent password

Tags: passwords, email, spam, email-spoofing, trojan

Just got an email that mentioned, in very broken english, having hacked my email etc. and actually managed to list my current password of that email account. The mail was, apparently, send by that very email and is, only in outlook, dated to be from march of **2030**.

I have searched a bit and im fairly certain that the email was spoofed and since the date is only seen in outlook and not in the webmailer of my service, that this is another simple trick. What I am concerned about is the password not being tracked by my trusted data-breach tracker (haveibeenpwned).

Is there a reasonable way that this is something to be concerned about? I mean if they had what they said they would have, they couldve just send me a short clip or simple picture to ensure payment and if they had actually gotten a trojan on my OS, some ransomware could get them probably more or atleast, again, guaranteed payment.

Comment: This is a common scam.While haveibeenpwned might not have your password, there are plenty of other databases out there that could have been used. The point is, they are not the one who hacked you (someone hacked a website that contained your password) and, of course, they are not from the future.